# Arrays can not be added to localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am creating todolist with vanilla js. I am triyng to get tasklist from localstorage, but when I set the array to localstorage, it shows empty.

Here is the code

```
const list = document.getElementById("list");
const toasterClose = document.getElementById("close")
const toast = document.getElementById("liveToast");
const toastInfo = document.getElementById("toast-info");
var tasklist;

if(localStorage.tasklist){
    var tasklist = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasklister"))
}else{
   var tasklist = []
}

console.log(tasklist);
function newElement(){
   const task = document.getElementById("task").value;

   if(task !== ""){
     const info = "Item added to list";
     const li = document.createElement("li");
     const spanClose = document.createElement("span");
     li.textContent = task;

     li.onclick = (e) =>{
        if(e.currentTarget.classList.contains("checked")){
            e.currentTarget.classList.remove("checked")
        }else{
            e.currentTarget.classList.add("checked")
        }
      }
    
      spanClose.innerHTML = "x"
      spanClose.classList.add("close");
    
      spanClose.onclick = (e) => {
          const index = tasklist.indexOf(e.target.parentElement);
          tasklist.splice(index,1);
          localStorage.setItem("tasklister",JSON.stringify(tasklist));
          e.target.parentElement.remove();
      }
    
      li.append(spanClose);
      tasklist.push(li);
      localStorage.setItem("tasklister",JSON.stringify(tasklist));
      list.append(li);
      toester(info)
    }else{
      const info = "Empty element cannot be added to the list";
      toester(info);
    }
   }

   function toester(info){
       toast.classList.remove("hide");
       toast.classList.add("show");
       toastInfo.innerHTML = info;
    }

   toasterClose.onclick = () =>{
     toast.classList.remove("show");
     toast.classList.add("hide");
    }
```

[image]

Why it is not adding and get the tasklister from local storage? İt shows on the browser but when I look to localstorage it show empty array.

Comment: Probably because you're trying to add HTML elements with event listeners to the array. Just add the _text_ of the todo to the array and save that. Then rebuild the elements from that array.

Answer (score 3):

The Local Storage API only stores strings.  To store an array, you must stringify it to JSON and then parse it again when you want to read from the storage:

```js
const STORAGE_LOCK = "MY_AWESOME_APP_ARRAY";

function readArray() {
  const data = localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_LOCK);
  if (data === undefined) return null;
  return JSON.parse(data);
}

function writeArray(arr) {
  localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_LOCK, JSON.stringify(arr));
}
```

Just note that you `readArray` returns a static array that will not update your storage when you, for example, call `push`.  Instead, do something like this to add an item:

```js
writeArray([...readArray(), 23]) // adds `23` to the list
```

Personally, I would just opt for a class that abstracts out this logic for me:

```js
class DataStorage {
  static key = "MY_AWESOME_APP_ARRAY";

  static get data() {
    try {
      const data = localStorage.getItem(DataStorage.key);
      return JSON.parse(data);
    } catch (err) {
      this.data = [];
      return [];
    }
  }

  static set data(arr) {
     localStorage.setItem(DataStorage.key, JSON.stringify(arr));
  }

  static add(item) {
    this.data = [...this.data, item]; // pushes it into the array
  }
}

console.log(DataStorage.data); // []
DataStorage.data = [2, 5];
console.log(DataStorage.data); // [2, 5]
DataStorage.add(6);
console.log(DataStorage.data); // [2, 5, 6]
```